# Are there humans which the brain sends signals to the limbs faster than the average?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology

I have done some researches on the time taken by the brain to send signals, but I didn't find whether that time is the same amongst all humans or there are some differences, and I have based my question on an article which mentioned that Messi(one of the best players in soccer history)'s brain send signals to the limbs faster than the normal human (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27010676), so is this possible to happen.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Biology.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about this site and earn yourself your first badge. You surely did find an amusing paper! Good luck with your question!

Comment: Your question would be improved if you explained who "Messi" is.

Comment: helpful paper https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Experimentally-determined-conduction-velocity-of-a-nerve-impulse-in-a-mammalian_fig12_321016169

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the time it takes for a signal to travel from the brain to the limbs follows a normal distribution (which is reasonable), then certainly there are people who fall at the upper and lower ends of the distribution. In fact, it's relatively improbable that someone would fall right at the mean.

Consider the normal distribution below. If the mean for all humans is at the center of the distribution, then almost all fall above or below that mean. Whether Messi falls in the lower tail is a separate question.

[image: Normal]